# Behavior of virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have a question, here are two classes below:

```
  class Base{
      public:
          virtual void toString();       // generic implementation
  }

  class Derive : public Base{
      public:
          ( virtual ) void toString();   // specific implementation
  }
```

The question is:

- If I wanna subclass of class **Derive** perform polymophism using a pointer of type **Base**, is keyword virtual in the bracket necessary?
- If the answer is no, what's the difference between member function **toString** of class **Derive** with and without virtual?

Comment: It is optional but some consider it a matter of good style to be explicit about overriding member functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++03 §10.3/2:

> If a virtual member function vf is
>   declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or
>   indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name and
>   same parameter list as Base::vf is
>   declared, then **Derived::vf is also
>   virtual (whether or not it is so
>   declared)** and it overrides
>   Base::vf.

Answer (score 10):

That keyword there is strictly optional and makes no difference at all.

Comment: It makes no difference to the compiler. To the human reader it may in fact improve readability. I always explicitly state virtual at all levels of inheritance.

Answer (score 7):

The `virtual` property is inherited from the base class and is assumed to be present even if you don't type it out.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler already knows from the 'virtual' keyword in the base class that toString is a virtual method.  No need to repeat it.

Comment: One might add that it might make a difference for the human reader.

Answer (score 1):

***A function once a virtual always a virtual***.

So in any event if the virtual keyword is not used in the subsequent classes, it does not prevent the function/method from being 'virtual' i.e. be overridden. So the following guideline might help from a team development point-of-view :-

- If the function/method is supposed to
  be overridden, always use the
  'virtual' keyword. This is especially
  true when used in interface / base
  classes.
- If the derived class is supposed to
  be sub-classed further explicity
  state the 'virtual' keyword for every
  function/method that can be
  overridden.
- If the function/method in the derived
  class is not supposed to be
  sub-classed again, then the keyword
  'virtual' is to be commented
  indicating that the function/method
  was overridden but there are no
  further classes that override it
  again. This ofcourse does not prevent
  someone from overriding in the
  derived class unless the class
  is made final (non-derivable), but it
  indicates that the method is not supposed to be
  overridden.
  Ex: `/*virtual*/ void someFunc();`

Comment: For the case of "to be overridden always", one might want to add the pure specifier as well.

Comment: I think there's meant to be a comma between "overridden" and "always".  i.e. "always use the `virtual` keyword" and not "always overridden".

Comment: @Myke: Except that `pure` isn't a C++ keyword.

Comment: The "pure specifier" is of the form = 0, not a keyword.

Comment: @Myke: Well, well. Who would have thought... I didn't, anyway. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter to the *compiler* whether or not you supply the **virtual** keyword on derived versions of the function.

However, it's a good idea to supply it anyway, so that anyone looking at your code will be able to tell it's a virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of good style, and the user-programmer knows what's going on. In C++0x you can use [[override]] to make it more explicit and visible. You can use [[base_check]] to force the usage of [[override]].

If you don't want or can't do that, simply use the virtual keyword.

If you derive without virtual toString, and you cast an instance of Derive back to Base, calling toString() would actually call Base's toString(), since as far as it know's that's an instance of Base.