# Virtual function, how does they work?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, virtual-functions

In C++, i am not able to understand, when a base class pointer stores the address of derived class object it is not able to call the derived class member function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void show()
    {
        cout<<" In Base ";
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    int x;
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"In Derived ";
    }
    Derived()
    {
        x = 10;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Base *bp, b;
    Derived d;
    bp = &d;
    bp->show();
    cout << bp->x;  
    return 0;
}
```

According to me: 
`derived d` => allocates the memory to this object(therefore to x also ) say at address 200,
 `bp = &d;` => it allocated the address 200 to bp. Now it should be able to call bp->x? 
But it gives a error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behavior of virtual function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669681/behavior-of-virtual-function-in-c)

Comment: This question doesnt seem to be about virtual functions, but about Base not having a member called x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In C++, i am not able to understand, when a base class pointer stores
>   the address of derived class object it is not able to call the derived
>   class member *variable*?

Well yes you can, you just need to cast the pointer to the class where the member variable is present

```
cout << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bp)->x;
```

Comment: According to me 

 derived d => allocates the memory to this object(therefore to x also ) say at address 200,
bp = &d; =>    it allocated the address 200 to bp. Now it should be able to call bp->x?

Comment: The instance of `Derived` contains `x` but the pointer you are using is of type Base so you cannot use that to access x (in a straightforward manner). From a memory perspective you are right that the 'x' is there

Comment: can we also the call derived class funtion using type casting.If yes can you tell me the syntax, Thanks.

Comment: to call the derived class function you need to do the same i.e. `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bp)->show()` although as a general rule with dynamic_cast you should check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

`bp->x` gives an error because `bp` is a pointer to an object of type `Base`, and `Base` doesn't have a variable called `x`, only `Derived` does.

If `x` was moved up into `Base` it would be accessible from both `Base` and `Derived` if it's public or protected.

Comment: When pointer to a base class object stores the address of derived class object, shouldn't it be able to call the derived class members.

Comment: base class pointer stores that address where memory is allocated to the derived class object.

Comment: No, the compiler only knows it's of type `Base` and that it has a function called `show()`. It doesn't know anything about classes that inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Binding of names happens in run time. so at compilation bp is of type base. so compiler doesn't know anything about derived type assignment. so its saying there is no variable called x in base.

That's where concept of virtual functions come into picture. but hey are only for functions not variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is bp->x is a error?

Because at compile time, the compiler can't tell what it points to. What if it was *actually*, a pointer to the base class? Then, `x` would be completely absent from the underlying object...

**To answer the title question**: when you have a pointer to base class that actually points to a derived class instance, *then* a call to a public functions declared virtual in the based class and reimplemented in the derived class *will* end up being a call to the derived class' implementation of that function (there are subtelties involved, with private/public access and name hiding that may interfere, but this is roughly how it works).